# Hitting a specific jboss instance behind a load balancer

Tags: servlets, jboss

My webapp is deployed in a cluster of multiple JBoss instances. There is an admin page in the webapp to perform certain Jboss instance-specific operations.

The problem is that requests are sent to a load balancer instead of directly hitting specific individual instance.

Is there any way to direct request to a specific instance? Or at least when the admin page is up, all subsequent requests (Ajax) will stick to the original instance that serves the page at the beginning.

I don't think HttpSession is going to help here. I need to target specific instance and not maintaining the state of individual client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for how to configure for Sticky sessions.

Send all requests in a user session consistently to the same backend server known as persistence or stickiness. A significant downside to this technique is its lack of automatic failover: if a backend server goes down, its per-session information becomes inaccessible, and any sessions depending on it are lost. The same problem is usually relevant to central database servers; even if web servers are "stateless" and not "sticky".

Assignment to a particular server might be based on a username, client IP address, or by random assignment. While there are advantages and disadvantages to the approaches.

I would suggest to please go through below article in configuring JBoss under a cluster rather going in deep understanding unless and until you would want to know in deep.

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/beta422/html/clustering-http-nodes.html

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HTTPLoadbalancer